# duplicate xhr request angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-factory

I am working with Angular.Js and using factory to load my data, I have an issue where my request are duplicated.i am injecting another module named filter module.

my search module

```
 var searchjob = angular.module('searchjobs', ['infinite-scroll', '720kb.socialshare', 'ui.bootstrap', 'rzSlider','ngclipboard', 'filtermodule']);

searchjob.controller('jobListController', function jobListController($scope, $http, Session, baseurl, $window, job_service, search_service, $location) {
$scope.getJobList = function(page) {
        $scope.showLoader = 1;
        if (typeof(page) == "undefined") {
            page = 0;
        }
        $scope.page = page + 1;
        job_service.getJobList($scope.page).then(function(ls) {
            $scope.showLoader = 0;
            isProcessing = false;
            //$("body").css('overflow','hidden');
            if (ls.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
                    $scope.jobslist.push(ls[i]);
                }
                if (page == 0) {
               //     $("body").css('overflow','');
               //     $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }
                if (ls.length < $scope.NEW_SEARCH_PAGE_LIMIT || ls.length==1) {
                    $scope.nomorejobs = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $scope.nomorejobs = 1;
            }
        });
    };
})
```

filter module:

```
var filtermodule = angular.module('filtermodule', []);

filtermodule.factory('job_service', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {
        return {
            getlastestjobs: function () {
                return   $http.get('/recruiter/loadlatestjob').then(function (response) {

                    return  response.data;

                });

            },
            getJobList: function (page) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/newsearch', {params: {ajax: '1', page: page}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            getRecruiterFunctionalRole: function (page) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/getfunctionalrole', {params: {ajax: '1', page: page}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            workList: function () {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/worklist', {params: {ajax: '1',page:'1'}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            getChartData: function (startdate,enddate) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/getchartdata', {params: {ajax: '1',"startdate": startdate,"enddate": enddate}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            reloadGraph: function (startdate,enddate) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/newgetapplicationcounts', {params: {ajax: '1',"from_date":startdate,"to_date":enddate}}).then(function (response) {
                    
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            workListCount: function () {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/worklistcount', {params: {ajax: '1',page:'1'}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            referapplied: function (page) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/referappliedjobs', {params: {ajax: '1',page:page}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            referappliedjobcount: function () {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/referappliedjobscount', {params: {ajax: '1',page:'0'}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            getcompanyjobs: function (companyid,page) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/newcompany', {params: {"ajax": '1',"page":page,"companyid":companyid}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            getCompanydetails:function (companyid){
                return $http.get('/recruiter/getcompanydetails', {params: {"companyid":companyid}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            },
            getMinMaxFixedReferralReward: function () {
                return   $http.get('/newjob/getminmaxfixedreferalreward').then(function (response) {

                    return  response.data;

                });

            },
            getMinMaxPercentageReferralReward: function () {
                return   $http.get('/newjob/getminmaxpercentagereferalreward').then(function (response) {

                    return  response.data;

                });

            },
            getMinMaxPerHourReferralReward: function () {
                return   $http.get('/newjob/getminmaxperhourreferalreward').then(function (response) {

                    return  response.data;

                });

            }
        };

    }]);
```

[image]

Comment: just change your variable in your `if` condition and then try.
if (!$scope.page) {
            $scope.page = 0;
        }

Comment: you want to replace if (typeof(page) == "undefined") {  page = 0;  } with . if (!$scope.page) { scope.page = 0; }

Comment: yes i want you to replace and then check. if it resolve your issue.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: my problem is here getJobList: function (page) {
                return $http.get('/recruiter/newsearch', {params: {ajax: '1', page: page}}).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
            }, when i remove   return before $http it become single request but i cannot call it my controller, i am getting call to the undefined method then

Comment: my bad i misunderstood your problem. can you tell me how you are calling  `$scope.getJobList` function. i mean by some search field typing or something else.

Comment: am talking about your controller function not service function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222715/discussion-between-karthick-kumar-and-farhat-zaman).